# I only have the .mp4 files from a Sony XDCAM EX shoot, is there a way I can still convert them for use in AfterEffects on Windows?

Tags: after-effects, software-recommendation, conversion, mp4

I no longer have access to the original recordings and the weird excess of files that Sony likes to bundle with the video you actually need.

[image: like so]

I'm running Windows 8.1 and Adobe After Effects CS6, and I've now got Sony's "XDCAM EX ClipBrowser V2.6".

Is there a way around Sony's encryption or are my options limited to reshooting the whole project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

MP4 files should be all you need.  There shouldn't be any encryption on the files.  It is possible you may need to download a codec.  MP4 files are just a container format, so different codecs could be used within it.  It is possible that you don't have the needed codec installed, but if you do, the files should just open in After Effects without issue.

Comment: Though unlikely, the camera would shoot not in spec with the MP4 format if thats the case. Every codec supported by MP4 is supported by After Effects natively.

Comment: @ProfessorSparkles - yeah, can't think of any other reason it wouldn't work though, unless it has perhaps been otherwise misshapen by some other process.  I would fully expect it should just work, but I'd assume the OP already tried that and it didn't.